# Calculate a polynomial

Tags: python, function, increment, polynomials

I want to calculate a polynomial on x value. I tried to write 
a function that takes as argument an array of integer and integer x
the function will returns the value of the polynomial in x.

```
def pol(L, x):
    P = None
    for i in L:
        P = L[0] * (x ** 0) + L[1] * (x ** 1) + L[2] * (x ** 2)
    return P

L = [0, 2, 4]
x = 3
print(pol(L, x))
```

I also tried

```
def pol(L, x):
    P = None
    for i in L:
        j = 0
        P = sum(i * (x ** j))
        j += 0
    return P

L = [0, 2, 4]
x = 3
print(pol(L, x))
```

It will return 42 for this example.
I don't know how to increment.
Thanks

Comment: While it's a good exercise to code that up, I'd highly recommend you also check out [`numpy.polyval()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)

Answer (score 2):

Building up on your attempts, one straightforward way to get the polynomial would be the following:

```
def poly(p, x):
    val = 0
    for i, pp in enumerate(p):
        val += pp * x**i

    return val
```

There are faster and more elegant ways to do this, though. I'd strongly encourage you to use [`numpy.polyval()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) for efficiency.

Note that for the `numpy` implementation, `p[0]` is the highest order polynomial while for the example shown here, `p[0]` is the lowest order!

```
p = [0, 2, 4]
x = 3

poly(p, x)
>> 42

import numpy as np
poly(p, x) == np.polyval(p[::-1], x)
>> True
```